# Emulate mobile devices on Mozilla/TOR

Tags: debugging, mobile, emulation, mozilla, tor

I want to emulate phone oriantation on Mozilla. Thats how it should look like:

 (Image from Chrome)
But on Mozilla, It looks like this:

No matter what resolution I enter, resolution doesnt change visually. I dont know if thats a bug or if I'm doing something wrong but I dont think thats a bug. I also couldnt find any extensions for emulating devices. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I cant edit the message. The images are:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU7m7.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F4HN.png)
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLUfB.png)